# how to install ruby 2.4 on Centos 6.5

Tags: centos, ruby

Because yum install ruby results in a version 1.8, while most tools require at least ruby version 1.9, so I install from tar.

```
    wget http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/ruby-2.4.1.tar.gz
    tar zxf ruby-2.4.1.tar.gz
    cd ruby-2.4.1
    yum groupinstall "Development tools"
    yum erase ruby ruby-libs ruby-mode ruby-rdoc ruby-irb ruby-ri ruby-docs
    yum -y install zlib-devel curl-devel openssl-devel httpd-devel apr-devel apr-util-devel mysql-devel
    ./configure
    make
```

Results:

```
ruby -v
-bash: /usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory
```

Comment: `make` builds the binaries, if you want to install it into system as well, i'd guess you need to run `make install` as additional step. That's how it usually is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is much safer to install ruby using a download manager.
One such manager is [RVM](http://rvm.io/).

For a detailed description of using RVM, see the article
[How to Install Ruby 2.4.0 on CentOS/RHEL with RVM](https://tecadmin.net/install-ruby-2-4-centos-rvm/).

The article describes how to install ruby version 2.4, set it as the default
and test if the installation was successful.